# How to create opaque under layer with CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to add a opaque underlay using CSS.

Could you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

CSS

```
popUp#translucent{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:fixed;
    opacity: .4;
}

popUp#content{
width:400px;
height: 100px;

}
#popContainer{
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
display: visible;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="popContainer">
    <popUp id="translucent"></popUp>
    <popUp id = "content">
        <button class="btn large btn-custom" data-h="193" data-s="32" data-l="64" ,="" data-p="15">Alpha</button>
    </popUp>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CeRX3/

Thanks

Comment: Start with valid markup; `popUp` isn't an HTML element, it seems you just made it up. Also: `,=""`... what the?

Comment: @wesleyMurch I was trying to follow the guide on http://iwearshorts.com/blog/annoying-css-opacity-inherited-by-children/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to create underlay for a button using CSS.

Plz check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NejiHyuga/CeRX3/4/) made by using code from w3 schools.

**html**

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="transbox">
    <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
    This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
    This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
    This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
    This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
div.background
  {
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
  background:url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis.jpg) repeat;
  border:2px solid black;
  }
div.transbox
  {
  width:400px;
  height:180px;
  margin:30px 50px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  }
div.transbox p
  {
  margin:30px 40px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#000000;
  }
```

You can use above code. There is this problem with Opacity in CSS.

The Problem With CSS Opacity
    The problem occurs when we add child elements to the html element that this code 
    affects. All child elements will inherit the same opacity settings, even if you try to 
    specify full opacity for all those elements (which would be too troublesome to do 
    anyhow).

[The Hacky Solution](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/)
    How can we work around this problem? In some instances, you could visually mimic a 
    parent-child relationship between the elements using absolute positioning, and this 
    will resolve the problem.
Then if u want to solve your problem then you may have to use a work around method for the purpose.

Comment: I don't want to create an underlay for the button but rather a black opaque box behind the button. Does that make sense? Is this possible to accomplish with CSS?

Comment: plz check now if it meets u r requirement

Comment: Thanks but I think I am not explaining what I am trying to accomplish. Consider the example http://iwearshorts.com/opacity/, notice how the text is not opaque but the container behind it is? I am trying to achieve this same effect with my above code. I want the button and all other content within the box to be non translucent but the black box itself to be translucent. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for you updated answer.  However, consider when the opacity is lowered and the background color is black. http://jsfiddle.net/CeRX3/5/ Is it possible to make the text white and no opacity regardless of the properties of transbox?

Answer (score 0):

change your background colour to grey and the opacity to .1  in the translucent. it looks more translucent then.